# How to convert a regular dictionary into nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my original list of dictionaries.

```
[{"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Dutch", "IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":5.3},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"English", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":9.5},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Papiamento", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":76.7},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Spanish", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":7.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Balochi", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":0.9},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Dari", "IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":32.1},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Uzbek", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":8.8},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Ambo", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":2.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Chokwe", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":4.2}]
```

**I want to convert them into nested dictionaries(used for loading JSON file). Like:**

```
{"ABW":{"Dutch":{"IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":5.3},"English":{"IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":9.5},"Papiamento":{"IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":76.7},"Spanish": {"IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":7.4}},
 "AFG":{"Balochi":{"IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":0.9},"Dari":{"IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":32.1},"Uzbek":{"IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":8.8}},
 "AGO":{"Ambo":{"IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":2.4},"Chokwe":{"IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":4.2}}}
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work...

```
language = json.load(f)
language_dict ={}
for row in language:
    key1 = row.pop('CountryCode',None)
    key2 = row.pop('Language', None)
    language_dict[key1][key2] = row
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error in your post.

Comment: @ewong There is no error in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), or simply use the [`.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method of the `dict` class, i.e. change the following line:

```
language_dict[key1][key2] = row
```

to

```
language_dict.setdefault(key1, {})[key2] = row
```

Comment: I see now that I was misreading the example. I was reading it as a list of [{code, language}, {code, language}, ...], while what's actually needed is [{code, {language, language, ...}, {code, language...}]

Comment: @Selcuk Oh I got it. Thanks for your help sincerely. It works. This function is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is sameple code with defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
mylist = [{"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Dutch", "IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":5.3},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"English", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":9.5},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Papiamento", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":76.7},
 {"CountryCode":"ABW", "Language":"Spanish", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":7.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Balochi", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":0.9},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Dari", "IsOfficial":"T", "Percentage":32.1},
 {"CountryCode":"AFG", "Language":"Uzbek", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":8.8},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Ambo", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":2.4},
 {"CountryCode":"AGO", "Language":"Chokwe", "IsOfficial":"F", "Percentage":4.2}]


res_by_countrycode = defaultdict(dict)
for i in mylist:

    (_, country_value), (_, language_value), IsOfficial, Percentage = i.items() ## this unpack the values
    row = dict([Percentage, IsOfficial]) ## create dict with Percentage and IsOfficial 
    res_by_countrycode[country_value][language_value] = row ## with defaultdict , we can set add key to dict , with regular dict we will get keyRrror
print(dict(res_by_countrycode)) ## print result
```